# Problem with the latest MiKTeX pstricks update

Tags: pstricks

I have just updated MiKTeX and have found that `pstricks` now appears to cause a problem. The error message I'm getting is

> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pstricks\pstricks.tex"
>
> ! Undefined control sequence.
>
> l.31 \if@check@engine

Not sure what's happening here. If I stop `pstricks` from being loaded things work ok.

Is there a known problem with the latest `pstricks`?

Answer (score 5):

Wait for the next update or define until it happens:

```
\makeatletter
\newif\if@check@engine  \@check@enginetrue 
\makeatother
```

Report bugs to the PSTricks mailing list! See pstricks.tug.org

Comment: Thanks Herbert. Your code seems to work and I will report bug to mailing list.

Comment: next time! This time I already know the problem :-)

Comment: Where should the 'workaround' code be inserted - into pstricks.tex, or somewhere else?

Comment: Anywhere in the preamble before loading pstricks of your document. However, another update of TL or miktex should fix it

Comment: Herbert. Have tired to update miktex but no files show as needing updating. Also I 've updated pstricks manually and it didn't help the problem.

Comment: Put this file: http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/texnik/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty for a test into your documents directory. What happens if you run your example?

Comment: Have added your new pstricks.sty file to C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pstricks folder and things are working as they should again! Many thanks.

Comment: I  can confirm that MikTeX has still not the CTAN version.

Comment: Sames as above. MikTeX repos still show Dec-31 build, which has the 'bug', and the suggested workaround does not work for me. I've tried it in a variety of documents, including a bare minimal file, and still get the error. Again, I've rolled back to earlier pstricks, which seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The log shows that the error happens at line 31 in `pstricks.tex`, so you can comment the code below (line 31~35 in the `pstricks.tex`) like this:

```
%\if@check@engine
%  \ifx\c@lor@to@ps\@undefined
%    \def\c@lor@to@ps{\PSTricks_Not_Configured_For_This_Format}%  message for a pdflatex run
%  \fi
%\fi
```

---

I do not know whether any side effects would happen, but anyway it works. :P