# bug in latest build of PSTricks?

Tags: pstricks, bugs

Earlier today, I tried applying the update (on my MkTeX system, running under Win7 Pro) for PSTricks from 2.78 (27-Nov-17 build date) to 2.80a (31-Dec-2017 build date), and doing so caused a consistent and 'fatal' compile error:

```
 c:\users\me\Desktop\text\MiktTex\tex\generic\pstricks\pstrick.tex
 ! Undefined control sequence
 l.31 \if@check@engine
```

After reverting back to 2.78, compilation proceeded normally. When I diff'd the code in pstrick.tex, the only difference (that seems related to the issue is) in the new code, there is an additional line for \if@check@engine

```
 \if@check@engine
   \ifx\c@lor@to@ps\@undefined
     \def\c@lor@to@ps{\PSTricks_Not_Configured_For_This_Format}%  message for a pdflatex run
   \fi
 \fi
```

Here is the old code for comparison:

```
 \ifx\c@lor@to@ps\@undefined
   \def\c@lor@to@ps{\PSTricks_Not_Configured_For_This_Format}%  message for a pdflatex run
 \fi
```

So, something about the newly inserted command,  \if@check@engine, is causing compile fails. Was wondering if anyone can replicate/confirm at there end.

For the moment, the solution is to revert back to old pstricks, but thought I'd point out what seems to be a bug in the latest build.

Comment: It's already known: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408423/problem-with-the-latest-miktex-pstricks-update

Comment: Indeed -- it does seem like a duplicate. My apologies. I tried searching before I posted my comment, but missed it somehow.